# Como descobrir se o JavaScript está desabilitado?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Como eu posso verificar e mostrar a mensagem para o usuário que o JavaScript do navegador está desabilitado?

Por exemplo, ele vai fazer algo, e caso o JavaScript dele esteja desabilitado eu mostro esta mensagem para ele, para que ele venha habilitar no navegador.
Qual código pode me ajudar com isto?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Existe a tag `<noscript>` para esse propósito. Ela é renderizada apenas quando o JavaScript está desabilitado ou não é suportado.

Um exemplo seria:

```
<noscript>Para continuar habilite o JavaScript</noscript>
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou dar um conferida nesta documentação da mozilla e ver se funciona !

Comment: Obrigado novamente. Este <noscript> é o cara, só de ler a funcionalidade dele aqui e para que serve, vi que ele é um ótimo combatente, aos javascript desabilitados em navegadores, eu não o conhecia e agora já consigo resolver. Abraço !