# Redirecionar para uma URL caso o JavaScript esteja desabilitado

Tags: html5, redirecionamento

Usando a tag `<noscript>` é possível detectar quando o motor do JavaScript está desabilitado no navegador (conforme [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32562/8063)), mas como faria para redirecionar o navegador, depois de alguns segundos, para uma determinada página ou URL caso entre no `<noscript>`?

Além de redirecionar após determinado tempo (ex., 5 segundos), exibir antes uma mensagem no início do `body`, algo como:

```
<body>
   <noscript>
      Seu navegador não tem suporte ao JavaScript ou ele está desabilitado!
      <br>
      Você será redirecionado em 5 segundos...
   </noscript>
   ... resto do conteúdo
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das alternativas é colocar um `Meta Refresh` dentro do `<noscript>` com o caminho da página que vc quer encaminhar o usuário.

```
<noscript>
  <p>teste</p>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript">
</noscript>
```

Aqui tem mais detalhes sobre essa Meta Tag: [Encaminhamento de tela apos o Load](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381352/encaminhamento-de-tela-apos-o-load/381396#381396)

---

**Sobre a Meta dentro do Body** *(não indicado)*

Veja o que está na documentação: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> *"Se o atributo `http-equiv` estiver presente, mas não no estado de declaração de codificação: em um elemento `noscript` que é **filho de um elemento head**."*

**Ou seja:**  Se for uma `meta` com atributo `http-equiv` que não do tipo `http-equiv="content-type"` vc pode usar dentro de um `<noscript>` filho direto do `<head>`.

Então o ideal é declarar o seu código do `noscript` dentro do `head`,  o Chrome vai renderizar dessa forma o código acima. Repare que mesmo o `noscript` estando dentro do `head` a tag `<p>` é renderizada dentro do `body`. Acredito que esse comportamento possa variar de browser para browser...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então eu teria que usar dois `<noscript>`, um no body e outro no head?

Comment: @Sam não necessariamente, pq eu testei o Noscript com a Meta direto dentro do Body e funcionou. (Chrome 74, Win 10). Tem que ver como a tag Noscript é interpretada na Árvore de Renderização

Comment: Mas acho que colocar meta tags dentro do body é incorreto dentro das especificações do HTML5, não?

Comment: @Sam vou pesquisar, mas algumas tag normalmente usadas dentro do <head> tb são permitidas dentro do body, como <link> e <style>, a meta vou pesquisar, mas deve ser permitido, pq funciona :)

Comment: Dá uma olha [aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) :D

Comment: @Sam Editei a resposta e coloquei mais umas infos. Veja que mesmo tendo tags como <p> dentro do noscript que está no head, o browser coloca esse conteúdo dentro do body, e faz o redirecionamento como o esperado

Comment: tinha me lembrado `meta http-equiv="refresh"` mas não tinha pensado em usar assim, interessante a ideia

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu só lembrei pq outro dia mesmo usei ela em uma resposta rss.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a sugestão do hugocsl, resolvi inserindo um `<noscript>` **também** no `head` com a meta tag.

De acordo com [esta especificação HTML5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element), é permitido inserir a tag `<noscript>` dentro do `head`, conforme o texto relacionado aos elementos `meta`:

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>  If the `http-equiv` attribute is present but not in the encoding declaration state: in a
>   `noscript` element that is a child of a `head` element.

Tradução livre:

> **Contextos nos quais este elemento pode ser usado:**
>  Se o atributo `http-equiv` está presente mas sem declaração de codificação
>   (cito: `http-equiv="content-type"`): dentro de um elemento `noscript`
>   filho de um elemento `head`.

Então ficou assim:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=index2.html">
      </noscript>
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>
         Seu navegador não tem suporte ao JavaScript ou ele está desabilitado!
         <br>
         Você será redirecionado em 5 segundos...
      </noscript>
      ... resto do conteúdo
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O interesse é ver que o browser é inteligente o suficiente para pegar tags dentro do noscript e renderizar dentro do body. Pelo menos no Chrome... Depois olha a última imagem que atualizei na outra resposta como fica no navegador

Comment: Tá massa. vlw!!